# What is it ? the device that controls web usage

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

When I connect to an internet box in Wifi I am connected directly between my machine and the router, with nothing between
But I believe that we can put a server/device "between" which allows precisely in large companies, and when we connect to it, there is no wep/wpa key to enter, but we land on a welcome page to accept the T&Cs, do you know what the name of the device that handles this custom is? They can also block some ports, some websites, etc...

Answer (score 2):

"Captive Portal" is the term you want. That's the term for a Wi-Fi network setup where you are forced to deal with a web page before you can get access to the Internet.

The exact hardware involved to set up a captive portal can vary depending on how sophisticated your existing network infrastructure is. Some Wi-Fi routers have Captive Portal features built in, so in simple cases you can do it all in one box. In more sophisticated cases you might have separate APs, firewalls/routers, and web servers all set up in a coordinated way to create a captive portal environment.

Answer (score 1):

The 3 functions you're describing *could* simply be integrated into the router. Alternatively, they could be handled by a separate "firewall" appliance.

(Keep in mind that in larger corporate networks, a "router" is not the device that provides Wi-Fi; rather, it's the device that acts as an IP gateway. The building could have a hundred Wi-Fi *access points* all connected to a single router which sets the central policy – and that router often could handle such advanced functions all by itself.)

1. Blocking packets by port is done by a *firewall* (in a narrower sense) which you can find in practically every router (gateway) including even the one you have at home, although dedicated "firewall appliances" exist with more functions, but port-based filtering is universal. If a separate firewall appliance is used, it could be either in front or behind the router.
2. Blocking websites by domain name is often done via *DNS filtering,* using a specially configured DNS server which refuses to answer certain requests, or answers them with a fake reply. This may be part of a "firewall" appliance or just a regular server running DNS software (not necessarily part of the router at all).
3. Providing a "welcome page" to Wi-Fi clients is generally called a *captive portal* system. A captive portal usually builds on top of both features #1 and #2 mentioned above, so it is also often integrated into a router or a firewall appliance (but could also be handled by the Wi-Fi access point controller).

   (Captive portals generally are not proxy servers; they *could* be implemented as such, but it's more common to use transparent HTTP interception or DNS redirects for that purpose.)

Answer (score 0):

This think usually is proxy. This is software which is between you and Internet and **can** filter your requests and/or check answers from internet for malware.

The page you see is named landing page and can be organized to appear when you try to access some page via this proxy. Or when you successfully connect to the WiFi router. It can be named also WiFI captive portal but usually this name is used when you need to provide username and password to connect to Internet via this router.